# A continuous linear functional over $l_\infty$ which never achieves its norm

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Does there exist a continuous functional $A\in l_\infty^*$ such that $\forall x\in l_\infty$ $\lVert Ax \rVert \neq \lVert A \rVert \lVert x \rVert$?

Comment: Yes.  See [James' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James'_theorem).

Comment: Thanks. But do you know of any example of such a functional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Aweygan's comment, such functions exist. If $A$ is generated by a sequence in $\ell^1$, i.e.,
$$A(x) = \sum_{i \in \mathbb N} x_i \, y_i$$
for some $y \in \ell^1$, it is easily checked that $A$ attains its norm.

Hence, you need a functional from $(\ell^\infty)^* \setminus \ell^1$, but those functionals can only be constructed with the axiom of choice. Hence, you cannot write down an explicit example.